# Why does my first function to find a prime number take so much longer than the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, primes

I have two functions: `isPrime` and `alsoPrime`. Both are meant to return True or False if the number (x) is a prime number. `isPrime(x, pLis)` takes on a growing list of numbers of primes and looks to see if x is a multiple of any primes. `alsoPrime(x)` searches all odd numbers starting at 3, ending at the root of x. I then use a for loop, starting at 3 and going up in intervals of 2.

I expected isPrime to be faster because it should skip numbers, i.e.:

*isPrime -> 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19*

*alsoPrime -> 3, 5, 7, **9**, 11, 13, **15**, 17, 19*

But `alsoPrime` is immensely faster - 100X faster when searching through the first 1 000 000 numbers.

**Can someone please explain why? Is it taking a lot of time to call the `pLis` each time?**

```
def isPrime(x, pLis):
    for item in pLis:
        if x % item == 0:
            return False
    return True


def alsoPrime(x):
    for i in range(3, round(x**0.5)+1, 2):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

You're traversing through all of the primes you've discovered in `isPrime` when you really only need to traverse up to the square the candidate, like you do in `alsoPrime`. More iterations means slower code. Once quick way to verify this is to count the number iterations, like this:

```
def isPrime(x, pLis):
    for i, item in enumerate(pLis):
        if x % item == 0:
            print(f"{x} is not prime after {i} iterations")
            return False
    print(f"{x} is prime after {i} iterations")
    return True
```

Comment: OP has already found this is the case. The question was why more iterations is faster than less.

Comment: Ah whoops, I misread the question. Just corrected my answer.

Comment: Of course, thank you so much! I was so focussed on escape conditions for non-primes that I didn't realise that I would be iterating through the entire list in the case of a prime number